# Why does SqlConnection.Open fail from one of my network drives?

Tags: .net, sql-server, security, database-connection

I have a very simple .Net 4.5 exe (full source below) that just does SqlConnection.Open to a networked SQL Server, but if it is launched from one of my network drives it fails with a SqlException "*A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.*" (full exception details below). I'm used to seeing this error when server and/or instance names are misspelt, but this is not the case - the names are correct and the exe runs successfully from my local C: drive and from some mapped network drives, but just not one of them. Connecting to a local SQL Server instance works OK.

I've tried a number of networked SQL Servers and the behaviour is consistent. As already mentioned, connecting to a local SQL Server instance works OK.

I'm guessing this could be in some way related to CAS policy but from what I've Googled the limitations around loading code from network drives were removed in .Net 4.

Firstly, I want to know and understand what is going on. Secondly, I want to code up a test in the app so that if it is going to fail this way it can exit with a useful error message.

Any help much appreciated.

Rhys.

**Update1**: If I map the UNC path that does not work to a new drive letter it still doesn't work. Using a SQL Server alias or IP address in the connection string makes no difference.

**Update2**: Trying this under a user account with local admin rights on both the client PC and SQL Server server DOES work. This suggests the underlying problem is a security issue, but doesn't help with where (client or server) or what permission is missing.

---

**Full Source**

```
using System;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace SqlConnOpenTest
{
    class Program
    {
    static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Started.");

        try
        {
        SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder
        {
            DataSource = "MyServer\\MyInstance",
            InitialCatalog = "master",
            IntegratedSecurity = true
        };

        string connectionString = csb.ConnectionString;

        Console.WriteLine("Connection string is; \"{0}\".", csb);

        using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            sqlConnection.Open();
            Console.WriteLine("Connection opened successfully.");
            sqlConnection.Close();
        }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Finished, press Enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    }
}
```

**Full Exception**

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfoserverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfoserverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at SqlConnOpenTest.Program.Main()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
Error Number:-1,State:0,Class:20
```

Comment: do the ones it runs on / not run on have anything in common? for example, different domain? or perhaps the ones it runs on are all also mapped as drive letters?

Comment: A stretch but you may be connected to the network drive as another user and that user does not have authority.

Comment: Is this all tested from one machine? Or multiple?

Comment: @MarcGravell if there's a pattern to where it works and where it doesn't I can't see it.

Comment: @Blam - nice idea but nope - definitely doing all of this as 'me'.

Comment: I saw the same error messages on some sql express installations ... in my case the first connect call from my program failed while all following retries / connects worked ... maybe you want to check if a retry works?

Comment: @Rutix - tested from a number of machines by a number of people (all within the same enterprise network). Some developer type people, some sysadmin types, some user types. Same result every time.

Comment: @Rhys Jones - so it never works from that mapped network drive or only on some computers?

Comment: @PrfctByDsgn - nice idea - I updated my test app to try 3 times, then with a pause between tries, still no change.

Comment: Try pinging.  Try connecting to the ip address.

Comment: @Rutix - it never works from a drive mapped to the problem location.

Comment: @RhysJones This is a long shot but did you ever find a solution? Running into this same problem, precisely as you described. Thanks in advance